# How to create a typescript type to allow read-only tuples from a const

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface

```js
interface Test {
    data: string[]
}

const DATA_LIST = {
    USER: ["some string"],
    OTHER: ["some other string", "random value", "etc"]
} as const;

const test : Test = {
    data: DATA_LIST.OTHER
}
```

In the above code I cannot assign `DATA_LIST.OTHER` to `data` which is my use case where I have a couple of tuples that I want to assign to data.

I cannot assign it because it only accepts string[] while I am trying to assign a readonly tuple

Is there a better way to do this?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDKHIAmcYcAXMllKAOYDaAungL554ID2IWyAIgEFUggPoAZAJIBlVMgC8uAkQCq0gKIAlKgwBEGLgFsUNerqYAaZYQDyqABJad+oyi5gAFtGphaIOroWyLpQcCDERsgAbnAANgCuEIHBEGAI5mzIcBjI3LxgANwceXyQfFTofIr4RCRklALCYlKyAHR2jppsQA

Comment: If you are sure that the test won't modify the data, maybe you can use `interface Test { data: Readonly<string[]> }`? Here `test.data` can still be re-assigned unless you change it to `readonly data: ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem is simply this:

```
The type 'readonly ["some other string", "random value", "etc"]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'string[]'.
```

... which means that you can't assign a `string[]` to a `readonly string[]`.

If you want to reassign `test.data` at some other point in time, then you could simply do `data: [...DATA_LIST.OTHER]`, which will get rid of the `readonly` aspect and which allows you to assign to a simple `string[]` property.

If you do not want `test.data` to be reassigned you could change the type of the property to either `readonly string[]` or `string[] | readonly string[]`.